# On FormSubmit create new sheet, importrange and rename based on contents of column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, formulas

I have the following script, the idea being that when a user submits a form (and when the sheet populates that answer) it uses the information given to create a new sheet with some of the info they gave used to populate it.

So in step by step it should look like this:

- User submits form
- Sheet updates
- Sheet creates new tab/sheet
- Sheet renames newly created sheet to reflect the contents of column E
  (their name)
- Sheet actions an IMPORTRANGE in cell A1 of the newly
  created and named sheet.

This would have to work whenever a new entry is added.

This is what I have so far, the new sheet based on a template is working but I can't figure out the rename or the IMPORTRANGE parts. If anyone could take a look and give me a hand that would be ace!

```
function FormSubmit(){
  Logger.log('Form Submited');
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var Name = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 4).getValue(); 
  var templateSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Template');

 ss.insertSheet(1, {template: templateSheet});

  var sourceSheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  var sheetNumber, sourceSheet, newSheetName;  
  for( sheetNumber = 0; sheetNumber < sourceSheets.length; sheetNumber++) {
    sourceSheet = sourceSheets[sheetNumber];
    newSheetName = sourceSheet.getRange("E3").getValue();
   sourceSheet.setName(newSheetName);
  }
}
```

Comment: You can get the answers that were submitted in the Form from the "Event Object."  The Event Object is usually denoted by the letter `e`:  For example:  `function FormSubmit(e) {`  You are not getting the Event Object in your function that is installed as an On Form Submit trigger.  [Link to Apps Script Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)  You can get an the answer that is their name with either the `values` or `namedValues` property of the event object.  `var theirName = e.values[3];`  Get the value from the fourth element in the array.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you are asking about "IMPORTRANGE". Sandy already wrote a way to retrieve the name from the actual form submit, however, I will go with your method of pulling it from the spreadsheet as it makes little difference to actually setting the name of the sheet.

The simplest solution is to set the name of the sheet immediately on insert. Read on that [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#insertSheet(String,Object)) but in essence what we would do is instead of

```
ss.insertSheet(1, {template: templateSheet});
```

instead, let's say you store the name in a variable `newSheetName`. Then we will have

```
ss.insertSheet(newSheetName, 1, {template: templateSheet});
```

or if you do not care where the sheet is inserted (or to be exact you want it to be at the end) this also works:

```
ss.insertSheet(newSheetName, {template: templateSheet});
```

Now I would also like to address this block in general:

```
var sourceSheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
var sheetNumber, sourceSheet, newSheetName;  
for( sheetNumber = 0; sheetNumber < sourceSheets.length; sheetNumber++) {
  sourceSheet = sourceSheets[sheetNumber];
  newSheetName = sourceSheet.getRange("E3").getValue();
  sourceSheet.setName(newSheetName);
}
```

to start, `var sourceSheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();` can be entirely replaced with `var sourceSheets = ss.getSheets()` as you already retrieved the spreadsheet.

This block will perform a name set for all of your sheets. Which is something you might not want as you have your form responses as well as the template sheet.

Comment: Hiya Vytautas, thanks for your input. I want to use IMPORTRANGE to bring the contents of column D into the newly created and renamed sheet.

Here is a link to the sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UDAb8ATDChnVbi_2jktsoAfumrq0Tj8gO8xotYgb6JA/edit?usp=sharing

And here is a link to the form:
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScddKiapSIuapeTv9MPQMEEmY3VIt0ZIDt5mpGk_Sj7sXjxWg/viewform

Comment: @SL8t7 looks like something goes wrong with `var Name = e.values[4];` and it does not return the value. Check again (add Logger to see) what exactly you get in `e`. Otherwise, your script seems to work. You might want to also add `newSheet.showSheet()` considering the template is a hidden sheet.